# Testing custom process.stdio mock hangs in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, mocking, stdio

I am trying to create a node module based on node's internal process.stdio to have an object with `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` to use that is not tied to process in any way, to pass around and mock.

It its proving difficult to test this file for some reason. Even the minimal test of `new Stdio()` seems to "block" or "hang" jest. `--forceExit` works but there is some other weird or odd behavior. Is there anything specific about the code below that would cause the process to hang?

Here it is:

```
const tty = require('tty')

export function getStdout () {
  var stdout
  const fd = 1
  stdout = new tty.WriteStream(fd)
  stdout._type = 'tty'
  stdout.fd = fd
  stdout._isStdio = true
  stdout.destroySoon = stdout.destroy
  stdout._destroy = function (er, cb) {
    // Avoid errors if we already emitted
    er = er || new Error('ERR_STDOUT_CLOSE')
    cb(er)
  }
  // process.on('SIGWINCH', () => stdout._refreshSize())
  return stdout
}

export function getStderr () {
  var stderr
  const fd = 2
  stderr = new tty.WriteStream(fd)
  stderr._type = 'tty'
  stderr.fd = fd
  stderr._isStdio = true
  stderr.destroySoon = stderr.destroy
  stderr._destroy = function (er, cb) {
    // Avoid errors if we already emitted
    er = er || new Error('ERR_STDOUT_CLOSE')
    cb(er)
  }
  // process.on('SIGWINCH', () => stderr._refreshSize())
  return stderr
}

export function getStdin () {
  var stdin
  const fd = 0
  stdin = new tty.ReadStream(fd, {
    highWaterMark: 0,
    readable: true,
    writable: false
  })
  stdin.fd = fd
  stdin.on('pause', () => {
    if (!stdin._handle) { return }
    stdin._readableState.reading = false
    stdin._handle.reading = false
    stdin._handle.readStop()
  })
  return stdin
}

export function setupStdio () {
  var stdio = {}

  Object.defineProperty(stdio, 'stdout', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get: getStdout
  })

  Object.defineProperty(stdio, 'stderr', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get: getStderr
  })

  Object.defineProperty(stdio, 'stdin', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get: getStdin
  })

  return stdio
}

export default class Stdio {
  constructor () {
    const {stdin, stderr, stdout} = setupStdio()
    this.stdin = stdin
    this.stderr = stderr
    this.stdout = stdout
    return this
  }
}
```

This hangs the process in Jest, why?

```
import Stdio from './index'

test('works', () => {
  const x = new Stdio()
  expect(x).toBeTruthy()
})
```